# Erro no procedimento de DANFe![-2146233036] The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um sistema que realiza a impressão de DANFEs em `vb.net`, porém em um cliente específico ele está dando o seguinte erro:

> Erro no procedimento de DANFe![-2146233036] The type initializer for '' threw an exception

Dei uma olhada de perto no código e cheguei à seguinte função:

```vb
 Protected Overrides Sub ImprimeCabecalho()
   Dim empRz As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Razao
   Dim empCNPJ As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.CNPJ
   Dim empIE As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Fisco.IE
   Dim empEndereco As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.Endereco
   Dim empNumero As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.Numero
   Dim empBairro As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.Bairro
   Dim empCidade As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.Cidade
   Dim empUF As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.UF
   Dim empCEP As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.CEP
   Dim empTelefone As System.String = Configuracoes4.Empresa.Contato.Telefone

   Dim str As String = ""

   If Not Me.FontesDefinidas Then
      Me.DefineFontes()
   End If

 'Cabeçalho principal
   str += empRz + vbLf
   str += "CNPJ:" & empCNPJ & " IE:" & empIE + vbLf
   str += empEndereco & ", " & empNumero & " " & empBairro & "-" & empCidade & "/" & empUF + vbLf
  str += "CEP:" & empCEP & " Tel:" & empTelefone

MsgBox("1")

  Me.ImprimeSpoolerCentro2(str)

  Me.ImprimeSpoolerCentro(RetornaLinha("-", False))
'Informativo NFCe
  str = "DANFE NFC-e - Documento Auxiliar da Nota Fiscal Eletrônica para Consumidor Final" & vbLf
  If Configuracoes4.Empresa.UF <> "PR" Then
      str += "Não permite aproveitamento de crédito de ICMS"
  End If
  Me.ImprimeSpoolerCentro(str, FonteOpcao.Destaque)
End Sub
```

Nesta função tenho um msgbox que é disparado antes da função `Me.ImprimeSpoolerCentro2`, que recebe uma string como parâmetro, debugando o projeto a string está formatada normalmente, abaixo segue a função ImprimeSpoolerCentro:

```vb
Protected Sub ImprimeSpoolerCentro2(text As String)
    MsgBox("2")
    Me.ImprimeSpooler(text, , Nothing, Nothing, Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center, )
    MsgBox("3")
End Sub
```

O erro é disparado exatamente quando se faz a chamada da função, não chegando nem a exibir o MsgBox com o "2".

Alguém tem uma idéia do que possa ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema encontrado aqui foi que a versão do .NET instalado na máquina do meu cliente, era a versão 4.7 instalada em um windows 7 SP1 atualizado, baixei a versão para a 4.6 e funcionou perfeitamente, porém até eu perceber isto já havia passado 2 ou 3 dias.
É isso pessoal, só queria compartilhar a resolução com todos.